# Filter JSON data based on a value

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON data:

```
{
  "VMs":[
    {
      "ID":"VM-WIN7-64",
      "OS":"Windows 7",
      "FLAVOUR":"VM-IE8-001-preq",
      "ADAPTER":"Win 9",
      "Paths":"D:\\VirtualMachines\\Win7_X64_VM-001\\Win7_X64_VM-001.vmx"

    },
{
      "ID":"VM-WIN7-6",
      "OS":"Windows jj7",
      "FLAVOUR":"VM-IE8-001-preq",
      "ADAPTER":"Winjjjjj 9",
      "Paths":"f:\\VirtualMachines\\Win7_X64_VM-001\\Win7_X64_VM-001.vmx"

    }
  ]

}
```

In this JSON, I am getting the value  `"ID":"VM-WIN7-64"`. Using this ID, how can I filter the corresponding adapter name `"ADAPTER":"Win 9"` from this JSON data?

Comment: That depends on the language you are using to process the data. You rarely work with "raw" JSON data, it's usually converted to a language's native data types first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Array.prototype.filter` method.

```
var filtered = data.VMs.filter(function (element) {
    return element.ID == "VM-WIN7-64";
});
```

(where the `data` variable contains your entire JSON data "VMs" array)

Then, `filtered[0].ADAPTER` would have the value "Win 9"

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/R3QGB/)