# Parsing JSON Entry Quickly

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse some json file. Suppose I have the following

```
{"data" : [
  {"ID":12, country: "UK"},
  {"ID":13, country: "USA"},
  {"ID":14, country: "BRA"},
]}
```

But instead of just 3 entries, I have hundreds. I want to access the element with ID 13, say; do I have to loop the entire "data" list (the way I've been doing in nor is there a faster way to do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you change your data structure? Make the ID the key of an object instead of a value.

Comment: Have a look at underscoreJS, it gives you some very handy tools for this: http://underscorejs.org/.

Comment: @Barmar I cant :( Because I'm fetching the JSON from a website, so can't control that

Comment: Then there's no way to do it other than searching. If you need to do lots of searches on the array, convert it into an object after you receive it.

Comment: Btw, I don't think you will run into any performance problems doing loops like this. I worked with JSON files with 7000+ products and there is no perceivable lag. The only problem is if you do a DOM operation or something similar in each loop. And keeping your data in an array is way more practical than an object with the IDs as keys.

Comment: Are the IDs incremental, sorted and without gaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A per the post
[Filter JSON data based on a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849627/filter-json-data-based-on-a-value)

It would be something like

```
var filtered = yourjSondata.data.filter(function (element) {
    return element.ID == "13";
});
```

filtered[0].country might return you "USA"

NOTE: To Match the syntax include country in double quotes like

```
{"ID":"13", "country":"USA"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without further assumptions, I see no alternative to a linear search, like this:

```
var s = {"data" : [
  {"ID":12, country: "UK"},
  {"ID":13, country: "USA"},
  {"ID":14, country: "BRA"},
]};
function find( array, id) {
  var record = null;
  try { 
    array.forEach( function(item) { if( item.ID == id ) {
      record = item;
       }});
    } catch (e) {} 
  return record;
  }
find( s.data, 13)  // --> gives Object {ID: 13, country: "USA"}
```

Note: A `find()` function for arrays will be available as a built-in Array function as per ECMAscript 6.